# Erasing elements in a vector

Tags: c++, vector, erase, erase-remove-idiom

So I have a vector of unsigned ints (`vector<unsigned int>` is called `vector1`). I have another vector of a struct I created (`vector<struct>` is called `vector2`). `vector<int>` holds an integer that is the index of the `vector<struct>`. For example, let's say that `vector<int = {5, 17, 18, 19}`. That means `vector2.at(5) == vector2.at(vector1.at(0))`.

In the struct, I have a bool variable called `var`. In most cases, `var` is false. I want to delete all of the elements in `vector1` that have `var` = true.

What I did was:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vector1.size(); i++)
{
   if (vector2.at(vector1.at(i)).var)
    vector1.erase(vector.begin() + i);
}
```

The only problem with this is that it does not delete all of the true elements. I have run the for loop multiple times for all values to be delete. Is this the correct behavior? If it is not, where did I go wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `if (vector2.at(vector1.at(i)).var)`? `int` doesn't have a member `var`.

Comment: Yeah sorry I fixed it in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the [erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Erase-Remove) to delete elements from a vector.

```
v.erase(std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), value), v.begin);
```

`std::remove` moves the elements to the end of the vector and `erase` will erase the element from the vector.

Comment: I looked into that, but I wasn't sure how to set value to be the value of var in that element. As a work around, I just created another vector and stored the appropriate elements in the new vector.

Comment: Technically (and usually also practically) `remove` doesn't neccessarily move the elements to the end of the vector.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep a temporary vector, copy of `vector1` and iterate over it in the `for` loop and  delete from `vector1`.

Answer (score 1):

You are erasing elements in the vector while at the same time iterating over it. So when erasing an element, you always jump over the next element, since you increase `i` while having just shortened the vector at `i` (it would be even worse, had you used a proper iterator loop instead of an index loop). The best way to do this  would be to seperate both opretions, first *"marking"* (or rather reordering) the elements for removal and then erasing them from the vector.

This is in practice best done using the [erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom) (`vector.erarse(std::remove(...), vector.end())`), which first uses [`std::remove(_if)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) to reorganize the data with the non-removed elements at the beginning and returns the new end of the range, which can then be used to really delete those removed elements from the range (effectively just shortening the whole vector), using [`std::vector::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase). Using a C++11 lambda, the removal condition can be expressed quite easily:

```
vector1.erase(std::remove_if(                        //erase range starting here
                  vector1.begin(), vector1.end(),    //iterate over whole vector
                  [&vector2](unsigned int i)         //call this for each element
                      { return vector2.at(i).var; }),  //return true to remove
              vector1.end());                        //erase up to old end
```

**EDIT:** And by the way, as always be sure if you really need `std::vector::at` instead of just `[]` and keep in mind the implications of both (in particular the overhead of the former and *"maybe insecurity"* of the latter).